# why couldn't the configuration in bootstrap.yml work?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

bootstrap.yml & application.yml

```
zuul.SendResponseFilter.post.disable: true
zuul.SendErrorFilter.post.disable: true
zuul.TraceDebugPreFilter.post.disable: true
zuul.ServletDetectionFilter.pre.disable: true
```

It couldn't work because `com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter#isFilterDisabled` is `false`.

But when I set command line like:

```
-Dzuul.ServletDetectionFilter.pre.disable=true \
-Dzuul.SendResponseFilter.post.disable=true
```

Then `com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter#isFilterDisabled` is `true`.

what's the matter? how can I make the bootstrap.yml configuration work?

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about your project dependencies? It should work either way.

Comment: <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Comment: i think the configuration may be overrode by spring cloud.  because there's no extra configuration in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.ZuulProperties